# Install android apps on pepper´s tablet in Naoqi 2.5

Tags: android, nao-robot, pepper

I want to install an android app on Pepper with NaoQi 2.5. To achivie this is tried to use AlTabletService´s hidden method "_installApk". I built an APK in android studios and deployed it in pepper´s head, the APK file does exist in peppers head because when i ssh into pepper and use the "ls" command the file is listed. I then tried to install the apk:

```
qicli call ALTabletService._installApk /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/helloWorld/src/android/app-debug.apk
```

When i open the ADB debugger in pepper I can see the error message that the command gives:

```
I/ALTabletService/TabletService( 1175): Install Apk : /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/helloWorld/src/android/app-debug.apk
I/ALTabletService/APKHelper( 1175): Installing package /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/helloWorld/src/android/app-debug.apk UMA: false
E/APKHelper( 1175): Unable to download /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/helloWorld/src/android/app-debug.apk
E/APKHelper( 1175): java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/helloWorld/src/android/app-debug.apk
E/APKHelper( 1175):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:176)
E/APKHelper( 1175):     at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:125)
E/APKHelper( 1175):     at jp.softbank.tabletbrowser.helper.APKHelper.downloadUrl(APKHelper.java:239)
E/APKHelper( 1175):     at jp.softbank.tabletbrowser.helper.APKHelper.installApk(APKHelper.java:57)
E/APKHelper( 1175):     at jp.softbank.tabletbrowser.service.TabletService._installApk(TabletService.java:396)
```

It appears that there is a problem with the path to the file. However it should be right, when I press Tab to autocompleat the path to the file it does so successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ALTabletService is running on the tablet, not on Pepper's head, so it cannot access the unix filesystem on Pepper's head; it can, however, access any file exposed on Pepper's internal webserver (the way it does for webpages shown on the tablet) - so you need to do something like:

1) copy the apk to `/home/nao/.local/share/PackageManager/apps/helloWorld/html/app-debug.apk`

2) `qicli call ALTabletService._installApk http://198.18.0.1/apps/helloworld/app-debug.apk`

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to install android application on the pepper tablet. First of all, it is worth being mentioned that aldebaran and softbank community is extremely poor as far as I know. Besides, their documentation is also outdated. However, you need to jailbreak the tablet and root it in order to be able to connect android studio adb in to the robot tablet.

More details are available here: [pepper-tablet-jailbreak](https://github.com/LilithWittmann/pepper-tablet-jailbreak)